# How to create a button that continues running your code if you press it, but breaks it if you click elsewhere?

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code, if you run it you will see there is a "click to roll" text inside a rectangle. How can I make my code continue running if you click inside the rectangle, and break and close the code if you click outside the rectangle? Is there a way to do it with my current modules without adding a new one? Thanks.

```
import graphics
from graphics import *
from random import randrange
max_x = 500
max_y = 300
win = GraphWin("Dice Rolls", max_x,max_y)
#drives the program
def main():
   class dots():
       #Drawn dots
     def __init__(self,p_x=0,p_y=0,p_s=50):
       self.m_x  = p_x
       self.m_y  = p_y
       self.m_dice_size = p_s
       self.m_items = []
       dot_size = 4
       x = self.m_x
       y = self.m_y
       s = self.m_dice_size
       d = s/4
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+2*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+1*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+3*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+1*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+3*d), dot_size))
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.setFill('black')
        #Displays three dice images based on the random value
     def display_dice(self):
       return (self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def undraw(self):
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.undraw()
               #Drawn Dice
     def draw(self, p_win, p_num):
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.undraw()
       if (p_num==1):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==2):
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==3):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==4):
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==5):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==6):
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[2].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[5].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)

   #Prepares for next roll
   class dice_t:
     def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
       self.m_x = x
       self.m_y = y
       self.m_s = 50
       self.m_item = Rectangle(Point(self.m_x,self.m_y),Point(self.m_x+self.m_s,self.m_y+self.m_s))
       self.m_item.setFill('white')
       self.m_dots = dots(self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def display_dice(self):
       return (self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def draw_die(self, p_win):
       self.m_item.undraw()
       self.m_item.draw(p_win)
     def draw(self, p_win, p_num):
       self.draw_die(p_win)
       self.m_dots.draw(p_win,p_num)
     def undraw(self):
       self.m_item.undraw()
       self.m_dots.undraw()
   #Winnings and losing calculation
   def check_winner(p_rolls=[]):
      last = None
      total = 0
      triple = True
      for r in p_rolls:
        if (last!=None) and (last!=r):
          triple = False
        last = r
        total += r
      if (total==3) or (total==18):
        return 10
      elif (total==4) or (total==17):
        return 5
      elif (triple ==True):
        return 2
      return -1
   #Text and instructions/rules
   def get_bet(p_win,p_balance,p_def_bet):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,20), "MAKE YOUR BET: "))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,40), "BALANCE:"+str(p_balance)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,70), "Rules: "))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "If you roll a 3 or 18 in total your bet winnings will be 10x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,110), "If you roll a 4 or 17 in total your bet winnings will be 5x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,130), "If you roll triples besides a 3 and 18 your bet winnings will be 2x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,150), 'If you roll anything else, you lose your bet.'))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-59,190), Point(max_x/2+59, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'CLICK TO ROLL'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)

      bet_text = str(p_def_bet)
      bet_input = Entry(Point (max_x/2+100, 20),5)
      bet_input.setText(bet_text)
      bet_input.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      bet_text = bet_input.getText()
      bet = int(bet_text)
      bet_input.undraw()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
      return bet
   #Shows winnings, checks for winner, updates total, and returns the updated total
   def show_winnings(p_win, p_winnings):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "Your WINNINGS:"+str(winnings)))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'PLAY AGAIN'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
   #Shows bet
   def show_bet_invalid(p_win):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "YOUR BET WAS INVALID"))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'TRY AGAIN'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
   #Shows game over
   def show_game_over(p_win):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "YOU ARE OUT OF MONEY"))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'QUIT'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()


   # M A I N and balances along with random outputs
   #################################################

   dice = []
   for d in range(0,3):
     dice.append(dice_t(max_x/2-90+d*60,5))

   balance = 100
   def_bet = 10
   while ( balance > 0 ):
     bet_invalid = True
     while (bet_invalid):
       bet = get_bet(win,balance,def_bet)
       if (bet>=1) and (bet<=balance):
         bet_invalid = False
       else:
         show_bet_invalid(win)
     def_bet = bet
     rolls = []
     for r in range(0,3):
       roll = randrange(1, 7)
       dice[r].draw(win,roll)
       rolls.append(roll)
     winnings = check_winner(rolls) * bet
     balance += winnings
     show_winnings(win, winnings)
     for r in range(0,3):
       dice[r].undraw()
   show_game_over(win)

main()
```

Comment: In the future, please don't remove the initial question. You can comment on an answer and ask for clarification like you did. Or make a whole new question. But, drastically changing your question to a whole new question essentially invalidates answers people have already provided and makes it less useful for people who may see your question in the future.

Comment: Rolled back to previous version. As mentioned, please avoid drastically changing the question, especially if there are already answers posted. If you need clarification on an answer, use comments. If solving this problem exposes a new one, please start a new question.

Comment: If you need the text from your reverted post to facilitate starting a new one, you can find it in the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53870638/revisions).

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Detect if you click inside a box in Python Zelle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863106/5771269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It may not be the best but it works. Im sure it can be improved, i did this pretty quick.

I have created a modified Rectangle class based off of [the Rect class here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PointsAndRectangles)

```
class Rect:

    """A rectangle identified by two points.

    The rectangle stores left, top, right, and bottom values.

    Coordinates are based on screen coordinates.

    origin                               top
       +-----> x increases                |
       |                           left  -+-  right
       v                                  |
    y increases                         bottom

    set_points  -- reset rectangle coordinates
    contains  -- is a point inside?
    overlaps  -- does a rectangle overlap?
    top_left  -- get top-left corner
    bottom_right  -- get bottom-right corner
    expanded_by  -- grow (or shrink)
    """

    def __init__(self, pt1, pt2):
        """Initialize a rectangle from two points."""
        self.set_points(pt1, pt2)

    def set_points(self, pt1, pt2):
        """Reset the rectangle coordinates."""
        (x1, y1) = (pt1.x, pt1.y)
        (x2, y2) = (pt2.x, pt2.y)
        self.left = min(x1, x2)
        self.top = min(y1, y2)
        self.right = max(x1, x2)
        self.bottom = max(y1, y2)

    def contains(self, pt):
        """Return true if a point is inside the rectangle."""
        x,y = pt.x,pt.y
        return (self.left <= x <= self.right and
                self.top <= y <= self.bottom)

    def overlaps(self, other):
        """Return true if a rectangle overlaps this rectangle."""
        return (self.right > other.left and self.left < other.right and
                self.top < other.bottom and self.bottom > other.top)

    def top_left(self):
        """Return the top-left corner as a Point."""
        return Point(self.left, self.top)

    def bottom_right(self):
        """Return the bottom-right corner as a Point."""
        return Point(self.right, self.bottom)

    def expanded_by(self, n):
        """Return a rectangle with extended borders.

        Create a new rectangle that is wider and taller than the
        immediate one. All sides are extended by "n" points.
        """
        p1 = Point(self.left-n, self.top-n)
        p2 = Point(self.right+n, self.bottom+n)
        return Rect(p1, p2)

    def __str__( self ):
        return "<Rect (%s,%s)-(%s,%s)>" % (self.left,self.top,
                                           self.right,self.bottom)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r)" % (self.__class__.__name__,
                               Point(self.left, self.top),
                               Point(self.right, self.bottom))
```

Now you will want to store the rectangle that covers the area you want to see if they clicked on. I called it _CHK_REC. You want to declare it globally at the top right after your `max_x` and `max_y` like this:

`checkRec = Rect(Point(max_x/2 - 59, 180), Point(max_x/2+59, 230))`

You will also want this little function i made to check if it contains the point,

```
def inRec(ms, rec):
    """
    ms is the mouse,
    rec is the rectangle cords.
    """
    p = Point(ms.x, ms.y)
    return rec.contains(p)
```

In order to use this in your code you want to use it in your main loop right above where you declare `rolls = []`. The while loops will then look like this:

```
   while ( balance > 0 ):
     bet_invalid = True
     while (bet_invalid):
       bet = get_bet(win,balance,def_bet)
       if (bet>=1) and (bet<=balance):
         bet_invalid = False
       else:
         show_bet_invalid(win)
     def_bet = bet
     mouse = mouse = win.getMouse()
     if not inRec(mouse, checkRec):
         return 1
     rolls = []
     for r in range(0,3):
       roll = randrange(1, 7)
       dice[r].draw(win,roll)
       rolls.append(roll)
     winnings = check_winner(rolls) * bet
     balance += winnings
     show_winnings(win, winnings)
     for r in range(0,3):
       dice[r].undraw()
```

Doing this seems to do what you are looking for. Here is modified version of your code with my changes to make it easier. Hope this helps.

```
import graphics
from graphics import *
from random import randrange


class Rect:

    """A rectangle identified by two points.

    The rectangle stores left, top, right, and bottom values.

    Coordinates are based on screen coordinates.

    origin                               top
       +-----> x increases                |
       |                           left  -+-  right
       v                                  |
    y increases                         bottom

    set_points  -- reset rectangle coordinates
    contains  -- is a point inside?
    overlaps  -- does a rectangle overlap?
    top_left  -- get top-left corner
    bottom_right  -- get bottom-right corner
    expanded_by  -- grow (or shrink)
    """

    def __init__(self, pt1, pt2):
        """Initialize a rectangle from two points."""
        self.set_points(pt1, pt2)

    def set_points(self, pt1, pt2):
        """Reset the rectangle coordinates."""
        (x1, y1) = (pt1.x, pt1.y)
        (x2, y2) = (pt2.x, pt2.y)
        self.left = min(x1, x2)
        self.top = min(y1, y2)
        self.right = max(x1, x2)
        self.bottom = max(y1, y2)

    def contains(self, pt):
        """Return true if a point is inside the rectangle."""
        x,y = pt.x,pt.y
        return (self.left <= x <= self.right and
                self.top <= y <= self.bottom)

    def overlaps(self, other):
        """Return true if a rectangle overlaps this rectangle."""
        return (self.right > other.left and self.left < other.right and
                self.top < other.bottom and self.bottom > other.top)

    def top_left(self):
        """Return the top-left corner as a Point."""
        return Point(self.left, self.top)

    def bottom_right(self):
        """Return the bottom-right corner as a Point."""
        return Point(self.right, self.bottom)

    def expanded_by(self, n):
        """Return a rectangle with extended borders.

        Create a new rectangle that is wider and taller than the
        immediate one. All sides are extended by "n" points.
        """
        p1 = Point(self.left-n, self.top-n)
        p2 = Point(self.right+n, self.bottom+n)
        return Rect(p1, p2)

    def __str__( self ):
        return "<Rect (%s,%s)-(%s,%s)>" % (self.left,self.top,
                                           self.right,self.bottom)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r)" % (self.__class__.__name__,
                               Point(self.left, self.top),
                               Point(self.right, self.bottom))
def inRec(ms, rec):
    """
    ms is the mouse,
    rec is the rectangle cords.
    """
    p = Point(ms.x, ms.y)
    return rec.contains(p)

max_x = 500
max_y = 300
win = GraphWin("Dice Rolls", max_x,max_y)

checkRec = Rect(Point(max_x/2 - 59, 180), Point(max_x/2+59, 230))

#drives the program
def main():
   class dots():
       #Drawn dots
     def __init__(self,p_x=0,p_y=0,p_s=50):
       self.m_x  = p_x
       self.m_y  = p_y
       self.m_dice_size = p_s
       self.m_items = []
       dot_size = 4
       x = self.m_x
       y = self.m_y
       s = self.m_dice_size
       d = s/4
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+2*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+1*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+1*d, y+3*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+1*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+2*d), dot_size))
       self.m_items.append(Circle(Point(x+3*d, y+3*d), dot_size))
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.setFill('black')
        #Displays three dice images based on the random value
     def display_dice(self):
       return (self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def undraw(self):
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.undraw()
               #Drawn Dice
     def draw(self, p_win, p_num):
       for dot in self.m_items:
         dot.undraw()
       if (p_num==1):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==2):
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==3):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==4):
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==5):
         self.m_items[0].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)
       elif (p_num==6):
         self.m_items[1].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[2].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[3].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[4].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[5].draw(p_win)
         self.m_items[6].draw(p_win)

   #Prepares for next roll
   class dice_t:
     def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
       self.m_x = x
       self.m_y = y
       self.m_s = 50
       self.m_item = Rectangle(Point(self.m_x,self.m_y),Point(self.m_x+self.m_s,self.m_y+self.m_s))
       self.m_item.setFill('white')
       self.m_dots = dots(self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def display_dice(self):
       return (self.m_x,self.m_y,self.m_s)
     def draw_die(self, p_win):
       self.m_item.undraw()
       self.m_item.draw(p_win)
     def draw(self, p_win, p_num):
       self.draw_die(p_win)
       self.m_dots.draw(p_win,p_num)
     def undraw(self):
       self.m_item.undraw()
       self.m_dots.undraw()
   #Winnings and losing calculation
   def check_winner(p_rolls=[]):
      last = None
      total = 0
      triple = True
      for r in p_rolls:
        if (last!=None) and (last!=r):
          triple = False
        last = r
        total += r
      if (total==3) or (total==18):
        return 10
      elif (total==4) or (total==17):
        return 5
      elif (triple ==True):
        return 2
      return -1
   #Text and instructions/rules
   def get_bet(p_win,p_balance,p_def_bet):
      inst = []

      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,20), "MAKE YOUR BET: "))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,40), "BALANCE:"+str(p_balance)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,70), "Rules: "))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "If you roll a 3 or 18 in total your bet winnings will be 10x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,110), "If you roll a 4 or 17 in total your bet winnings will be 5x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,130), "If you roll triples besides a 3 and 18 your bet winnings will be 2x your bet."))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,150), 'If you roll anything else, you lose your bet.'))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2 - 59, 180), Point(max_x/2+59, 230)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'CLICK TO ROLL'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)

      bet_text = str(p_def_bet)
      bet_input = Entry(Point (max_x/2+100, 20),5)
      bet_input.setText(bet_text)
      bet_input.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      bet_text = bet_input.getText()
      bet = int(bet_text)
      bet_input.undraw()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
      return bet
   #Shows winnings, checks for winner, updates total, and returns the updated total
   def show_winnings(p_win, p_winnings):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "Your WINNINGS:"+str(winnings)))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'PLAY AGAIN'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
   #Shows bet
   def show_bet_invalid(p_win):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "YOUR BET WAS INVALID"))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'TRY AGAIN'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()
   #Shows game over
   def show_game_over(p_win):
      inst = []
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2,90), "YOU ARE OUT OF MONEY"))
      inst.append(Rectangle(Point(max_x/2-50,190), Point(max_x/2+50, 210)))
      inst.append(Text(Point(max_x/2, 200), 'QUIT'))
      for item in inst:
        item.draw(p_win)
      p_win.getMouse()
      for item in inst:
        item.undraw()


   # M A I N and balances along with random outputs
   #################################################

   dice = []
   for d in range(0,3):
     dice.append(dice_t(max_x/2-90+d*60,5))

   balance = 100
   def_bet = 10

   while ( balance > 0 ):
     bet_invalid = True
     while (bet_invalid):
       bet = get_bet(win,balance,def_bet)
       if (bet>=1) and (bet<=balance):
         bet_invalid = False
       else:
         show_bet_invalid(win)
     def_bet = bet
     mouse = mouse = win.getMouse()
     if not inRec(mouse, checkRec):
         return 1
     rolls = []
     for r in range(0,3):
       roll = randrange(1, 7)
       dice[r].draw(win,roll)
       rolls.append(roll)
     winnings = check_winner(rolls) * bet
     balance += winnings
     show_winnings(win, winnings)
     for r in range(0,3):
       dice[r].undraw()

   show_game_over(win)


main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I added it into my code and it works pretty well, is there a way to reduce the number of clicks and get rid of the blank screen after every time I press "Click to roll"? I edited my code in my question to the most up to date one.

Comment: @RyanM This is the first time i have used the graphics library so this may be 100% wrong. But id guess it has to do with the order you draw/undraw things in your get_bet method. Since you undraw everything at the end, my guess is that the blank screen is time between you undrawing everything at the end of get_bet and redrawing things in show_winnings(). So if you clear the get_bet window from the show_winning() function and then immediately draw the show_winnings() window in the same function it might remove the in-between screen. Also, please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I have tried to follow your comment, but have not been able to get rid of the blank screen yet. Is it possible for you to send me the code of what you mean? As of now I have not been able to figure it out. Thanks for all your help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RyanM if you ask a new question let me know what it is called i can answer and give you a more complete answer. Basically create a list in the same place you created checkRec called bet_list. then in your get_bet() declare bet_list global and change the list appends to append to bet_list and change the for loop that draws them to the new bet_list. and remove the for loop that undraws the items.  Then go to your show_winnings() and make the first thing it does be declare bet_list as global then iterate through bet_list and call undraw. after the loop set bet_list = []. so it can start again.

Comment: @RyanM Doing the above will get rid of the blank screen. You will still have an extra click needed to handle the box you enter the bet into. but like i said, this is first time i used graphics so take the code with a grain of salt.